# Issues with Progress Bar

Tags: php, sql

I have this progress bar and what is shown as the description is decided based on has the customer set his targeted reward or not (by checking in database if a value is null) but i set a value to be something else than null and it always prints the "if null" case. Can anybody help?

Code used when creating database:

```sql
  target varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
# I put the current value to be "Bitcoin"
```

My code that checks the value:

```php
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $username1, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stm_track = $conn->prepare("SELECT target FROM users WHERE username = :username");
        $stm_track->bindParam(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stm_track->execute();
        $row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (is_null($row['target'])) {
        echo "<strong>Bookmark a reward and track your progress!</strong>";
} else {
        echo "<strong>Track your progress for next reward: " . $row['target'] . "</strong>";
}
```

Comment: Is `username` actually an INT? (`PDO::PARAM_INT`) I assume not, meaning your query is always returning false.

Comment: Hm, I didn't check that before. Anyways, I changed that to `PDO::PARAM_STR` but still the same result.

Comment: It is "admin" @GrumpyCrouton

Comment: Also, if you used a PDO wrapper (such as the one I wrote called [GrumpyPDO](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/GrumpyPDO)), your entire query (including declaration) could be condensed to just 2 lines (1 for initializing the class, and 1 for the actual query) (The query would become `$row = $db->row("SELECT target FROM users WHERE username=?", [$username]);`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared your `fetch()` command incorrectly;

```
$row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Should be

```
$row = $stm_track->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

These kinds of mistakes are easy to make when you are writing directly to the PDO class, I suggest using a PDO wrapper which handles this more automatically for you.